# How do I add a 3rd player to my simple java dice game?

Tags: java

I was hoping if someone can point me in the right direction.  The code below is my program for a two player dice game. I need to add a third player but not sure how.  So far we have covered if else statements, switches and loops - so anything else I am not allowed to use as we haven't covered it yet.  I've looked through the questions but I am not finding anything which answers my query, can anybody help please?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class dice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fP, sP;
        int dice = 0, dfPTot = 0, dsPTot = 0, round = 0, fPScore = 0, sPScore = 0, fPScoreR = 0,
                sPScoreR = 0;

        System.out.println(
        "Welcome to the online interactive dice game.\n\n\t
        * To complete the 5 rounds you will need two players and three dice
        !");
        System.out.println("\nPlayer 1, please state your name: ");
        fP = input.next();
        System.out.println("Welcome " + fP + "\n\nPlayer 2, please state your name: ");
        sP = input.next();
        System.out.println("Welcome " + sP + "\n\nLet's begin!");

        for (int count = 1; count <= 5; count++) {
            System.out.print(fP + " please throw your three dices and then input 
                                            your total dice score
            : ");
                        dfPTot = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print(sP + " please throw your three dices and then input
                        your total dice score
            : ");
                        dsPTot = input.nextInt();
            round = dfPTot + dsPTot;
            System.out.print(" The round total is: " + round + " \n");

            if (dfPTot > dsPTot) {
                fPScore = fPScore + round;
                fPScoreR += fPScore;
                sPScore = sPScore + 0;
                sPScoreR += sPScore;
            } else {
                sPScore = sPScore + round;
                sPScoreR += sPScore;
                fPScore = fPScore + 0;
                fPScoreR += fPScore;
            }
        }

        dfPTot = fPScore = round = 0;
        fPScore = fPScore + fPScoreR;
        sPScore = sPScore + sPScoreR;

        if (fPScore > sPScore) {
            System.out.println(fP + " is the Dice Master scoring: " + fPScore + " points");
        } else {
            System.out.println(sP + " is the Dice Master scoring: " + sPScore + " points");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get to use arrays? Because what I'd do is store player data into a bean, then create an `ArrayList<Player>` which lets you store multiple players (so you could expand it to be a three-player game, four-player game, etc.)

Comment: We haven't covered arrays yet - but i do know some students have used it for this specific task.  So how would i go about using an array? it looks to be the effective way for this program? and what is a bean? (sorry completely new at this)

Comment: It's fine! A Java bean is basically an object with private properties (it doesn't sound like you've covered object-oriented programming though). It would be effective, because your Player bean would be able to hold 'name', 'score', and any other attributes that you'd like to store per user. You may want to ask your professor/teacher if arrays can be used.

Comment: haha you're right there we haven't covered either which is why I had to ask as all the answers on stackflow include arrays. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(Assuming you can NOT use arrays, objects etc.)**

You would hopefully never ever have to design it like this normally. Anyway, pretty much all variables with sP(second player) and fP(first player) in their name needs to have a third one, prefferable tP(third player).

Then you can start copy pasting and change the logic in the final if-else statement to fit a third player.

(It really hurts to tell you to do it like this, just promise to never design anything like this ever in the future) :)

Comment: This is correct, and you're correct; it's painful to think about doing it without using arrays or objects

Comment: haha we had to build a program based on a graphical design - so no choice! I guess it has sound purpose as it has helped with understanding loops etc. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: - on my if statement to add the round to the player who rolled the highest, I am clueless on how to add a third player into this equation: if (dfPTot > dsPTot) .....?? would I need to do more if statements to cover all the outcomes?

Comment: @user3058983 yes ofc. Just nest a new if/else. (I would use methods for it). But, might i say that you don't check if there are equal roll ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use an `Arraylist` and loop through it to ensure that each player has its chance. An advantage of using an `Arraylist` is that you can change the size dynamically. So your implementation should work for n players.

this snippet allows you to initialize an arraylist for players. You have to import `java.utils` package though.

```
ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
```

To add players; just ask first how many players there are. Read that by input, or use a constant. Then use the next to add n players. (`max_players` = amount of players)

```
for(int i = 1; i <= max_players; i++) {
    System.out.println("\nPlayer " + i + ", please state your name: ");
    String name =input.next();
    // add to array
    players.Add(name);
}
```

Once done with this, you have a list of players. Just do this again for the game itself. Tip : use two loops. One loop for rounds, and one inner loop, that each player has a chance to play a round.

If you want to access the array, you can use the methods, provided in [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

for example; `players.size()` gives the current amount of players in the array. or `players.get(0)` gives the first player's name in the array, and ect ...

Please check the documentation for more possibilities. Try to implement such control structure, that you have a dynamic code at the end. I'm not going to put a complete solution, try it yourself first. Self-education is a good way understand the concept.

If you have a problem with the implementation later, feel free to [search it on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=) or ask it if you cannot find a solution to your future problem.

good luck and happy coding.

PS: actually, working with objects (OOP) would make it easier. Just make a class `Player` with `name` and `score` field. Then use that as type for the array.

Comment: (psst...`"\nPlayer " + i`...`)

Comment: I agree with your postscript; it'd be the best way to conceptualize it. It all comes down to whether or not arrays and having external objects are allowed or not (unfortunately).

Comment: Thank you KarelG - I will do some research on arrays I have a great book to guide me along with your answer!